# Función con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Espero que me puedan ayudar a que el codigo a continuación no ocupe muchas líneas de codigo como lo que ocupa actualmente.

Tengo un proyecto en Laravel y estoy añadiendo algo de JavaScript.

Tengo un listado de `pacientes` en una tabla que al darle clic en un paciente **me muestra el nombre y el apellido**, después en varios inputs tengo dos `button`, **uno toma lo que seleccioné en `pacientes` (nombre y apellido)** y el otro **borra**.

El siguiente codigo lo hace bien, mi pregunta es si existe una forma mas rápida o reducir el código para no tener que andar escribiendo mucho código.

**Código JavaScript:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('agregar800').addEventListener('click', agregaTextot800);
  document.getElementById('borrar800').addEventListener('click', borrartextot800);
  document.getElementById('agregar815').addEventListener('click', agregaTextot815);
  document.getElementById('borrar815').addEventListener('click', borrartextot815);
  document.getElementById('agregar830').addEventListener('click', agregaTextot830);
  document.getElementById('borrar830').addEventListener('click', borrartextot830);
  document.getElementById('agregar845').addEventListener('click', agregaTextot845);
  document.getElementById('borrar845').addEventListener('click', borrartextot845);
  document.getElementById('agregar900').addEventListener('click', agregaTextot900);
  document.getElementById('borrar900').addEventListener('click', borrartextot900);
  document.getElementById('agregar915').addEventListener('click', agregaTextot915);
  document.getElementById('borrar915').addEventListener('click', borrartextot915);
});

function agregaTextot800(e) {
  var inputNombre = document.getElementById('t800');
  var resultadoclick = document.getElementById('resultadodesdetabla').innerText;
  inputNombre.value = resultadoclick;
  e.preventDefault();
}

function borrartextot800(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var borrartextoeninput800 = document.getElementById('t800');
  borrartextoeninput800.value = "";
}

function agregaTextot815(e) {
  var inputNombre = document.getElementById('t815');
  var resultadoclick = document.getElementById('resultadodesdetabla').innerText;
  inputNombre.value = resultadoclick;
  e.preventDefault();
}

function borrartextot815(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var borrartextoeninput815 = document.getElementById('t815');
  borrartextoeninput815.value = "";
}

function agregaTextot830(e) {
  var inputNombre = document.getElementById('t830');
  var resultadoclick = document.getElementById('resultadodesdetabla').innerText;
  inputNombre.value = resultadoclick;
  e.preventDefault();
}

function borrartextot830(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var borrartextoeninput830 = document.getElementById('t830');
  borrartextoeninput830.value = "";
}

function agregaTextot845(e) {
  var inputNombre = document.getElementById('t845');
  var resultadoclick = document.getElementById('resultadodesdetabla').innerText;
  inputNombre.value = resultadoclick;
  e.preventDefault();
}

function borrartextot845(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var borrartextoeninput845 = document.getElementById('t845');
  borrartextoeninput845.value = "";
}

function agregaTextot900(e) {
  var inputNombre = document.getElementById('t900');
  var resultadoclick = document.getElementById('resultadodesdetabla').innerText;
  inputNombre.value = resultadoclick;
  e.preventDefault();
}

function borrartextot900(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var borrartextoeninput900 = document.getElementById('t900');
  borrartextoeninput900.value = "";
}

function agregaTextot915(e) {
  var inputNombre = document.getElementById('t915');
  var resultadoclick = document.getElementById('resultadodesdetabla').innerText;
  inputNombre.value = resultadoclick;
  e.preventDefault();
}

function borrartextot915(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var borrartextoeninput915 = document.getElementById('t915');
  borrartextoeninput915.value = "";
}
```

Y otros de los problemas que tengo es que en el button de `pacientes` cuando agrego se me sube para arriba la pantalla, como que se actualiza.

Espero que me hayan entendido con mi planteo.

Trato de hacer clic en el botón paciente para que aparezca el nombre y luego en los inputs de acuerdo al horario tomar ese nombre y colocarlo con el botón.

Comment: Puedes usar classes "agregar" y "borrar" para seleccionarlos todos a la vez con un bucle.
Y las funciones puedes pasar la id como parámetro.

Comment: Buen día, podrías utilizar `Livewire` y cada `input` relacionarla a una propiedad pública. [Información adicional](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties). Ya no utilizarías `JavaScript` para esa parte pero creo que encontrarías otros beneficios.